# Cloud task deadline more 30 sec

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-tasks

I use the cloud task without a problem. I have some task that's longer than the 30s it has by default. Is possible to extend it? Because I have some task that are quite long.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a [task](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.locations.queues.tasks#resource:-task), you can specify the parameter [`dispatchDeadline`](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.locations.queues.tasks#:%7E:text=045123456Z-,dispatchdeadline,-string). It set the timeout for the task.

By default it's 10 minutes, I'm surprised of your 30 seconds. If you need more help, share pieces of your code!